# The Dimension of the Solution Set of a Set of Non-affine commutative Polynomial Equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

I am reading [the webpage](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Encalg/DOWNLOAD2010/DOCUMENTATION/html/NCBIGDOCch24.html) to learn how to determine the dimension of the solution set of a set of polynomial equations. For the first case (the commutative polynomials), it is mentioned that if it is affine polynomials, one uses the Krull dimension or trancendance degree. However, the non-affine case is not introduced, and I am very interested in this case, especially multivariate quadratic polynomial equations.

Could anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're looking for solutions of some system of polynomials $f_1,\cdots,f_m\in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ in $k^n$ (or $\Bbb A^n_k$, depending on your viewpoint) this is *exactly* the affine case. Why do you think you need the non-affine case?

Comment: @HankScorpio I think I had a misunderstanding of  'affine polynomials'. Does it mean polynomials with finite variables? I thought it means linear polynomials.

Comment: I can't say without more context. Regardless, the statement in my previous comment applies to *any* system of polynomials.